# Find modified files and echo them into a txt file on server root

Tags: linux, file, shell, echo

I'd need a shell command to show of the last modified and new files on the whole server (recursive) and echoing them into a txt file in the root.

Has anybody something like this?

I tried

`find / - mmtime 30  -printf "%AD %Ar - %p\n" 2> /dev/null | sort -r > /lastmodified.txt`

to post all names of all modified files from the last 30 days into a txt file in root, but it shows me only the files of the server itself and not the directories where my websites are uploaded to.

Thank you in advance - I am not an expert, and this is what I found so far. It is relative urgent as I need this to fix hacked files which has happend last week.

Comment: Use `-mtime -30` instead of `- mmtime 30`.

Comment: created just an empty file. I need the modified files from the last 30 days. Thank you for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

From http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/Unix/FindCmd.htm:

```
find . -mtime 0   # find files modified within the past 24 hours
find . -mtime -1  # find files modified within the past 24 hours
find . -mtime 1   # find files modified between 24 and 48 hours ago
find . -mtime +1  # find files modified more than 48 hours ago
```

Make sure that you have only one 'm' and a minus sign in `-mtime -30`, as suggested in chorobas comment, to get last 30 days. `-mtime 30` would give just files exactly 30 days ago.

You may want to use option `-daystart` to get files of last 30 days starting from midnight instead of just 30*24 hours ago. Use `%TD` and `%Tr` instead of `%AD` and `%Ar` to get modification times (instead of access times).

The final command would then be:

```
find / -daystart -mtime -30 -printf "%TD %Tr - %p\n" 2> /dev/null | sort -r > /lastmodified.txt
```

Note that the sort will break in January as 12 is sorted before 01. If you want to make sure the dates are always in order, use for example time definition `%T+` (2012-11-29+21:07:41.0000000000) or `%Tu/%Tm/%Td %TH:%TM` (12/11/29 21:07)

Answer (score 0):

What about inotify-tools

https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki#wiki-getting

http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait

---

inotifywait example 2

#!/bin/sh

EVENT=$(inotifywait --format '%e' ~/file1)

[ $? != 0 ] && exit

[ "$EVENT" = "MODIFY" ] && echo 'file modified!'

[ "$EVENT" = "DELETE_SELF" ] && echo 'file deleted!'

# etc...